# Android - black screen conflict with app background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-webview

I am using a `WebView` to load my local `HTML` file. I deployed this in the Tab, a black screen appears during scrolling and selecting the `EditText`.

After doing some homework I found out this, it is a conflict with the `Android` theme. The black screen is the theme, if I change it to transparent 
(`ex:android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent`) then a transparent screen conflict.

I tried a lot to solve this but couldn't. Please let me know if there are any solutions?

This is not for `WebView` even when i put few edit text in a layout and select it and scroll same black (android theme) screen appears.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to open new tab 
new activity is launched but webview is not loaded at that time 
so in between this time you get the black screen

can you post the code